# On a K3S cluster, YCSB pod stops loading data to MongoDB pod early

Tags: mongodb, k3s, ycsb

I have a 3 node K3S setup. I have a MongoDB statefulset with 3 replicas and a YCSB statefulset with one replica. I expose port 2222 on the YCSB so i can SSH onto it in order to load data onto my mongoDB.

When connected to the ycsb pod i run
`/root/ycsb-0.17.0/bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P /root/ycsb-0.17.0/workloads/workloade -threads 8 -p recordcount=90000000 -p mongodb.url=mongodb://mongo-1.mongo.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/ycsb?w=0`
mongo-1 is the primary pod in the statefulset

the workload file is:

```
recordcount=1000
operationcount=1000
workload=site.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload

readallfields=true

readproportion=0
updateproportion=0
scanproportion=0.05
insertproportion=0.95

requestdistribution=zipfian

maxscanlength=100

scanlengthdistribution=uniform
```

This starts running and does write some records however it just goes back to console after 30/40 seconds with no error or success message:

```
root@ycsb-0:~/ycsb-0.17.0/workloads# /root/ycsb-0.17.0/bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P /root/ycsb-0.17.0/workloads/workloade -threads 16 -p recordcount=45000000 -p mongodb.url=mongodb://mongo-1.mongo.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/ycsb?w=0
java -cp /root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/conf:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/conf:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.4.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/lib/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/lib/core-0.17.0.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/mongodb-binding-0.17.0.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.8.0.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/mongodb-async-driver-2.0.1.jar:/root/ycsb-0.17.0/mongodb-binding/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar site.ycsb.Client -db site.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P /root/ycsb-0.17.0/workloads/workloade -threads 16 -p recordcount=45000000 -p mongodb.url=mongodb://mongo-1.mongo.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/ycsb?w=0 -load
Command line: -db site.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P /root/ycsb-0.17.0/workloads/workloade -threads 16 -p recordcount=45000000 -p mongodb.url=mongodb://mongo-1.mongo.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/ycsb?w=0 -load
YCSB Client 0.17.0

Loading workload...
Starting test.
2023-10-18 09:27:49:191 0 sec: 0 operations; est completion in 0 second 
mongo client connection created with mongodb://mongo-1.mongo.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/ycsb?w=0
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
2023-10-18 09:27:59:091 10 sec: 4740 operations; 471.08 current ops/sec; est completion in 1 day 2 hours [INSERT: Count=4766, Max=1002495, Min=202, Avg=23133.45, 90=95039, 99=293631, 99.9=999935, 99.99=1002495] 
2023-10-18 09:28:09:091 20 sec: 27052 operations; 2231.2 current ops/sec; est completion in 9 hours 15 minutes [INSERT: Count=22316, Max=1193983, Min=34, Avg=6448.71, 90=554, 99=100287, 99.9=398591, 99.99=993279] 
2023-10-18 09:28:19:092 30 sec: 53661 operations; 2660.9 current ops/sec; est completion in 6 hours 59 minutes [INSERT: Count=26619, Max=990719, Min=35, Avg=5375.07, 90=308, 99=100287, 99.9=301567, 99.99=600063] 
2023-10-18 09:28:29:092 40 sec: 144099 operations; 9043.8 current ops/sec; est completion in 3 hours 27 minutes [INSERT: Count=90518, Max=695807, Min=25, Avg=1644.49, 90=113, 99=90751, 99.9=199551, 99.99=399359] 
root@ycsb-0:~/ycsb-0.17.0/workloads#
```

I am new to using mongoDB and ycsb so any help would be appreciated!